# WPF : Definition Control Template by programmatically

Tags: wpf, templates, controls

We can make WPF Custom Control for overriding some control's look&feel, like icon button.

```
public class MyButton : Button {

    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }
...
}
```

But I think that way has a some problem. It causes a some issue when I distribute the Custom Cotrol 'MyButton'. Because MyButton dependent on external resource, the WPF Style MyButton. So I need to distribute two files : MyButton.cs and MyButton.WPF.

So, How can I definite a Conotrol Template by programmatically?

(Of cause, another way to solving the problem is making WPF User Control. but my point is not that.)

**Note : I found some resources about this issue. That was a Inline XAML scripting. But to me, the XAML scripting is not option. Because I'm learning on WPF so I want to know WPF thatself, not a trick.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not distribute the code, you distribute a dll that contains the class and the generic.xaml

That way another designer/developer can 'override' the template and your template stays as a safe fall-back.

**EDIT**

Defining a Template in code is no fun (a lot of code, hard to debug, hard to maintain) but it can be done:

```
var template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(MyControl));
```

**EDIT2**

Another hack is to specify the template in a long string and use the XAML Parser to load it.

Comment: Thanks. But problem is still left. When I distribute the Custom Control by source code, not assembly, I need include two files : XAML and .cs.

And frankly, my interest is Definition Control Template by programmatically, not distribution.

thanks.

Comment: Then use the part that is in the edited part of my answer. Another hack is to specify the template in a long string and use the XAML Parser to load it.

Comment: @mjk6026, BTW: xaml is WPF too. Just another way of writing the same thing.